# Check the Role in Router-flux

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a problem with a user's Role.

I use Router-flux to the router and the scenes in the app.

I have a page: **App.js** in which I defined the scenes, and I have defined a text in the right navBar for the logout. Now the problem is that, this logout text should be available only for a particoular role, but this role is definied in another page.

The real problem is that App.js is the first page that will be load when the app stars. So the role results "Undefined".

So the question is: How can I do, to check the role and don't show Logout text in the navbar (in the App.js) ?

**App.js**

```
<Scene
  key="homepage"
  component={Homepage}
  type="reset"
  leftTitle="Home"
  leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
  rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
  rightTitle={Roles !== "PLUS" ? "Logout" : ""}
  onRight={
    Roles !== "PLUS"
      ? () => App.logout()
      : () => {}
    }
  navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#56cbbe" }}
/>
```

**Homepage.js**

```
class Homepage extends Component {
  render() {
    const Roles = global.user.data.Roles;
    //......
```

EDIT:

I have done in this way:

```
export function RolesFunction(){
  Roles = global.user.data.Roles;
  isLogged = false;
  if (Roles == "PLUS") {
    var isLogged = true;
  }
  return isLogged
}

class Homepage extends Component {
 .....
```

And import the value in App.js but it doesn't work because don't find "data"

Answer (score 0):

create a component with `const Roles` and `export` it. Then `import` it in App.js. So you can use that component where you want.